# Prove that $f(x)=(2^{|x|})-(2^{(-x)})$ is many - one

Tags: functions

I have tried plotting the graph and got the answer. Is there any solution to this question without using graphs ?

Comment: Maybe too much of substitution and testing ?

Comment: $f(x) = 2\sinh (x\log 2)$ for $x>0$ and $f(x) \equiv 0$ for $x \leq 0$.

Answer (score 2):

$f(-1) = f(-2)$ but $-1 \neq -2$.

Comment: But what about positive values of $x$ ?

Comment: That is exceptional, is it so ? I doubt the claim and that's why.

Comment: @SamRubenAbraham Many-to-one just means not one-to-one. All one must do is find two different inputs that map to the same output.

Comment: Ok, so it means that not every input needn't yield the same image, right ? Only a few values yielding the same image is sufficient to make the function a many-one, right ?